# Can we use @RestClientTest when the rest template has interceptors using Spring boot 1.5.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.x (Spring 4.2.x), and I created a RestClientSdk spring component class as shown here:

```
@Component
public class RestClientSdkImpl implements RestClientSdk {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public RestClientSdkImpl(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
    ...
    //other methods kept out for brevity
}
```

I have also defined a DefaultRestTemplateCustomizer spring component as shown here:

```
@Component
public class DefaultRestTemplateCustomizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {

    private LogClientHttpRequestInterceptor logClientHttpRequestInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public DefaultRestTemplateCustomizer(LogClientHttpRequestInterceptor logClientHttpRequestInterceptor) {
        this.logClientHttpRequestInterceptor = logClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(logClientHttpRequestInterceptor);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));
    }

}
```

With that, I've defined a test class as shown below that uses the @RestClientTest annotation as shown below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(RestClientSdk.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
/*
 * The RestClientTest only includes the most minimal configuration to include a rest template builder, 
 * so we include the rest sdk auto config within the scope of the test 
 */ 
@ImportAutoConfiguration(RestSdkAutoConfiguration.class)
public class RestClientApplicationBehaviourTest{

    @Autowired
    private RestClientSdk restClientSdk;

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer;

    /**
     * A simple Http Get that retrieves a JSON document from a rest server and 
     * produces a plain old java object as a response.
     */ 
    @Test
    public void testPlainHttpGet() throws IOException{
        //ARRANGE
        RestClientDto<?> simpleGetRequest = simpleHttpGet();
        mockRestServiceServer.expect(once(), requestTo("http://localhost:8080/account/1234567890"))
                                   .andRespond(withSuccess(IOUtils.getInputAsString("/stubs/account.json"),MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        //ACT
        Account account = restClientSdk.send(simpleGetRequest, Account.class);
        //ASSERT
        mockRestServiceServer.verify();     
        Assert.assertNotNull(account);
        Assert.assertNotNull(account.getAccountId());
        Assert.assertNotNull(account.getFirstName());
        Assert.assertNotNull(account.getLastName());
    }
...
//not including other methods for brevity 
}
```

---

**PROBLEM**

---

Because the MockRestServiceServer builder overrides the BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory in my rest template with a MockClientHttpRequestFactory, I am getting a null response from my body. This is because the logging interceptor is reading the input stream coming from the response and as such the stream no longer has content to read. The BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory would prevent that from happening. Now, I know that as of Spring 5.0.5, there is an extra option in the MockRestServiceServer builder called *bufferContent*, but I don't have the option of moving to Spring 5.x (Spring Boot 2.x), so I was wondering if there is a way to get this configured using Spring Boot 1.5.x / Spring 4.2.x.

I thank you in advance!

Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to workaround the issue, I needed to define a test configuration, that would allow me to override the client request factory. Please see the code below. It is a bit hacky, but I suppose the real solution here would be to upgrade to Spring 5.x / Spring Boot 2.x.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MockRestServiceServerConfiguration {

    /**
     * Wrap the Mock Rest client factory in the buffered one.  
     * @param restClientSdk The rest client SDK containing the rest template to use.
     * @return The mock rest service server to use.
     */
    @Bean
    public MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer(RestClientSdkImpl restClientSdkImpl) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restClientSdkImpl.getRestTemplate();
        MockRestServiceServer server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

        //need to do this because getRequestFactory returns InterceptingHttpRequestFactory wraping the mock rest service server request factory
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> templateInterceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(null);

        //now we wrap the delegate, which should be the mock rest service server request factory 
        BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory bufferingFact = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(restTemplate.getRequestFactory());
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(bufferingFact);
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(templateInterceptors);
        return server;
    }
}
```